# Paginate constantly updating feed in django?

Tags: django, pagination

The obvious problem is that loading further pages in an updating feed would lead to loading some content more than once.

Is there a good built-in way to perform such a task? I think the paginator object wont really work unless used with reversed queryset which however is allegedly very memory inefficient. Another solution I could think of (when ordering by time) is sending a timestamp of the last object on the page, saving it in front-end and for the next request send this time to django do a time__gte for n+1 objects and slice off the first one.
Would probably do the trick quite well but its anything but intuitive.

Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in system that can handle what you are asking for.

What you are describing is called Seek Pagination. Check out https://nordicapis.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-api-pagination/ fo an explanation of Seek Pagination.

Comment: Thank you for the input and the valuable ressources, very much appreciated!